# Set two instance variables and show in console - Command Line Tool - (Not working)

Tags: objective-c, command-line, console, getter-setter

Situation:

- Set two instance variable
- Display variables in the console

(I know that I can use properties instead 
of coding the setter and getter myself but 
I like to understand why my code is not working.
The output on the console I get is:

> 2012-01-12 12:04:23.099 Test212[5894:707] Number: 0.000000 - Balance:
>   0.000000.

Why I don't get the values I set? Number = 1234 & Balance = 500?

)

BankAccount.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BankAccount : NSObject
{
    double bankAccountBalance;
    double bankAccountNumber;
}

-(void) setBankAccountBalance: (double)b;

-(void) setBankAccountNumber: (double)n;

-(double)showBankAccountBalance;

-(double) showBankAccountNumber;

@end
```

BankAccount.m

```
#import "BankAccount.h"

@implementation BankAccount

-(void) setBankAccountBalance: (double)b
{
    b = bankAccountBalance;
}

-(void) setBankAccountNumber: (double)n
{
    n = bankAccountNumber;
}

-(double)showBankAccountBalance
{
    return bankAccountBalance;
}

-(double) showBankAccountNumber
{
    return bankAccountNumber;
}
@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BankAccount.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        BankAccount *account1 = [[BankAccount alloc] init];

        [account1 setBankAccountNumber:1234];
        [account1 setBankAccountBalance:500];

        NSLog(@"Number: %f - Balance: %f.",[account1 showBankAccountNumber], [account1 showBankAccountBalance]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the wrong assignments in the setter methods. They should be

```
bankAccountBalance = b;
```

and

```
bankAccountNumber = n;
```